# jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined:940

Tags: javascript, jquery, rhomobile

In my (rather complex) rhomobile application, I'm getting the following error in my log file, and after that, the application hangs:

```
E/Web Console( 3257): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined:940
```

This error seems to come from the following JavaScript function:

```
/**
 * Returns a function to use in pseudos for input types
 * @param {String} type
 */
function createInputPseudo( type ) {
  return function( elem ) {
    var name = elem.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    return name === "input" && elem.type === type;
  };
}
```

Which is (only) called by JavaScript itself:

```
// Add button/input type pseudos
for ( i in { radio: true, checkbox: true, file: true, password: true, image: true } ) {
  Expr.pseudos[ i ] = createInputPseudo( i );
}
for ( i in { submit: true, reset: true } ) {
  Expr.pseudos[ i ] = createButtonPseudo( i );
}
```

These pseudos seem to help with converting elements to texts... but how can I trace on when and why the error occurs? It only occurs sometimes at some devices...

Comment: That part of the jQuery code is *not* where the problem is happening. The problem is happening because something is passing jQuery (somewhere from outside the library) a parameter that *should* be a DOM element, but isn't. It won't be possible for anybody to tell you where that's happening. Use a non-minified version of jQuery and then get a stack trace when the exception occurs.

Comment: This error is saying that `elem.nodeName` is undefined, therefore you cannot call `toLowerCase()` on it. `toLowerCase()` is a pure JavaScript function, not one of jQuery's. The function, `createInputPseudo` is not a jQuery function, it is created with vanilla JS. Even the caller is vanilla JS

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that? Now I've added try catch in the jQuery... with logging...